# developer view css style different in actual devices

Tags: html, css, styles, developer-tools

I don't know if this is a normal error in web developer but if this happen lots of time when you are designing, can you give me advices on how can I fix this issue?

I often happened this to my website. when on the developer view, all css style are perfectly good and fit on the design I like, but when I check on the actual devices, some of designs are missing, and sometimes it didn't show up the exact design and css. I still don't know the reasons why in actual devices are different from the developer view.

the most difficult and stressful thing here, is when you trying to fix the issue but don't know where the error is, because in the developer view all css style and design is perfectly good and fit. so even you are trying to adjust some css code you still don't know if that is the exact css you need to work out.

can anyone give me advices how to work out with this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Usually these kind of errors happend when your styling is fixed. For example, do this:

```
 width: 177px;
```

Instead of :

```
 width: 177vw;
```

Also make sure your alignment is on point.

Comment: thank you for your advice in width, but what if the issue is this  (border-radius:5% 5% 0% 0%/10% 10% 11% 11%;) this border-radius is not showing on the devices, but on the developer view is okay.

Comment: try this resource: http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/

Comment: i think the issue of border-radius is in ios devices only, because on android devices is fine.